# any guess why I can't get arView's width and height...?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

```
struct ARViewContainer:UIViewRepresentable{

func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  CustomARView {
    var arView = CustomARView(frame: .zero)
    arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
    context.coordinator.view=arView
    context.coordinator.width = Int(arView.bounds.width)
    context.coordinator.height=Int(arView.bounds.height)
    wwidth=Int(arView.bounds.width)
    hheight=Int(arView.bounds.height)
    print("makeui \(arView.bounds.width)")
```

my code is...as above.
I think it's simple but don't know why I can't get width and height of arview

Comment: What do u mean u can't? isn't the width and height at this point zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving the bounds of the `arView`, in which you have set its frame to `.zero`. Hence, the frame for arView is `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)`. You have set the `context.coordinate` size in the following lines:

```
context.coordinator.width = Int(arView.bounds.width)
context.coordinator.height=Int(arView.bounds.height)
```

...but this does not change the frame of the `arView`. To fix this, you need to set the width and height of the `arView`:

```
var arView = CustomARView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: given_width, height: given_height))
```